# Azure - Docker : Remote error : bad certificate :

Tags: azure, certificate, docker

I created VM using the following syntax

docker-machine_linux-amd64 create \
-d azure \
--azure-subscription-id="" \
--azure-subscription-cert="mycert.pem" \
machine-name

When i try to get info regarding the Docker that's hosted on Azure using the following syntax , i get bad certificate error, not sure what's wrong. I have been using the certificate for quite sometime , never had any issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full solution but hope it will help ...

I had the same probleme when I created my 2nd azure docker VM. The 1st one worked just fine.
I compared the home directory of the two machines and realized there was no .docker directory in the "non working" VM.
On my "working" VM, this directory have a bunch of files in it :
- ca-key.pem, ca.pem
- cert.pem
- client.csr
- extfile.cnf
- key.pem
- server-cert.pem, server-key.pem, server.csr

I copy-pasted the files and voila !
But not sure how I got the files in the first place, since I am not the one who created the 1st VM.

Both azure VMs were created using an ubuntu VM and access to both azure VMs was ok from this ubuntu VM. From MobXTerm, on my host laptop, however, access was ok only for the 1st azure VM and I got the "bad certificate" error for the 2nd azure VM.